# Borderlands 2, fast travel stations, how do I know whether I can return?

Tags: borderlands-2

Some of the fast travel stations in Borderlands 2 are one-way, like the one on Bloodshot Ramparts. I can travel *from* that location, but I can't travel directly to it.

Is there any way to know this when I'm at the station, coloring, symbols, text in the fast travel dialog?

I mean, without actually travelling through it and testing it? It would be handy to know if this was possible to learn beforehand, so that I know if I can take a quick trip back to Sanctuary to stock up on ammo and empty my inventory, without having to play a large swath of the map again to return.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Exit-only fast travel stations will look like this (has yellowish text and a sign similar to a 'No U-turn' sign):

[image]
<sup>Image source: [Borderlands Wiki, "Fast Travel" article](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Fast_Travel)</sup>

Comment: That is the exact station I was at, and it's also named "Escape", wonder if that holds true for the rest of them as well, but the U-Turn sign was a dead giveaway now that you made me aware of it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Not sure about the word "Escape" in the name, but the yellow text and no U-turn sign should be the same for other exit-only Fast Travel stations.

Comment: There's a station which I believe is called "Terminus Plateau"; it's an exit-only station in the "End of the Line" area.